# What is the difference among "reprender", "regañar" and "reprochar" to translate "rebuke"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I have translated "rebuke" into Spanish. It is a verb. These are the three translations for it:

- [reprender](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W4C4U2o)
- [regañar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VhQ2pWs)
- [reprochar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W5AZj56)

What is the difference among them?

The sentence is the following:

> Peter **rebuked** to me that I didn't do well in the project.

Hypothesis: "reprender" only means the rebuke, "echar en cara" and "reconvenir" are another translations of rebuke, "regañar" has more meanings

Answer (score 5):

They are roughly equivalent, and all they can be apt translations of *rebuke*.

- ***Reprender*** is more appropriate for more "formal" situations, in which the person who rebukes has some authority over the other (an employer, a teacher), or where the rebuking is done with circumspection and intent of correction. **Reconvenir** is a (less used) synonym.
- ***Regañar*** is for more "hot" situations, the person who rebukes is typically angry and tired (akin to "scold"). In Argentina (at least) a more used (slightly [colloquial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WGR22yF)) term is ***retar***.
- ***Reprochar*** is (rather like **reproach**) to let a person know that we strongly disapprove some concrete act of him/her.

Comment: I'd go further and say that _reprender_ and _regañar_ are better for vertical relationships (boss to employee/parent to child), while reprochar is also suitable for horizontal ones: there can actually be [_reproches cariñosos_](https://www.google.com/search?q="reproche+cariñoso"&oq="reproche+cariñoso")

Comment: Me gusta el uso de "**reprochar**" para traducir "**rebuke**" en las siguientes oraciones: `Supreme Court Gets a Rare Rebuke` y `The Supreme Court's rebuke`

Comment: Otro significado de la palabra "rebuke" es "**corregir**".